# Function that returns JSON object from .json file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a function that takes the data from a local `.json` file. Mine is `products.json`. This is the function that I'm trying to define:

```
async function getJSON_Format(){

    let response = await fetch(api);
    let data = await response.json();
    
    // console.log(data);

    return data;    
    
}
```

`api` is the file path of `products.json`. What I'm trying to do is to get all the data from products.json and store it in a JSON object variable like that `let json_object = getJSON_Format();`, but it returns a promise.

What could I do about that?

Comment: Please note that when you use "JSON object" you mean "JS object".

Comment: A function marked `async` always returns a Promise. The return type is not `json`, it is `Promise<json>`.

Comment: `getJSON_Format` won't return a "JSON format". It will return a JS object.

Comment: Just really noticed that the fetch api's `json` method which returns a [promise of] javascript _object_ really doesn't help newbie understanding of the difference does it @evolutionxbox ! sigh.

Comment: @jamiec Perpetuating a common misunderstanding doesn't help either

Comment: @evolutionxbox do you mean my answer? I didnt pay much attention to the variable names to start with, my bad!

Comment: @Jamiec no worries. The answer you gave is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is `async` so you need to `await` it. So do:

```
let obj = await getJSON_Format();
```

Which itself needs to be in an `async` function.

The other option is to treat it as a `Promise` and use `then`

```
getJSON_Format().then(obj => {
  // do something with obj here
});
```

Please note I've changed your variable names from `json_object` to simply `obj`. The concept of a "JSON object" is a misnomer. Something is either JSON (text) or an object (Javascript)

Comment: I tried the first option and wrote `console.log(obj)` and nothing has changed